# Generalized Farkas Lemma

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Farkas lemma can be stated as follow:

If for all $\mu$ such that $\mu^T\cdot a_i \geq 0$ implies that $\mu^T\cdot b \geq 0$ then $b=\sum \lambda_i a_i$ with $\lambda_i \geq 0$

I need a generalized version which goes as follows:

Let $\alpha_i \geq 0$. If for all $\mu$: $\mu^T\cdot (b-\sum a_i I_{\mu^T\cdot a_i < 0}) \geq 0$ then: $b=\sum \lambda_i a_i$ with $0 \leq \lambda_i \leq \alpha_i$

Here $I_{a<0}$ is 1 when $a<0$ and 0 otherwise.

The idea is that for each $\mu$ we have the signs of $\mu^T\cdot a_i$ and accordinly we pertube the score function, when $\mu^T\cdot a_i < 0$ we enlarge the score by $-\alpha_i \mu^T\cdot a_i$ and over all we end up with positive score.

When $b=\sum \lambda_i a_i$ with $0 \leq \lambda_i \leq \alpha_i$ the assertion follow, i.e. $\mu^T\cdot (b-\sum a_i I_{\mu^T\cdot a_i < 0}) \geq 0$ for all $\mu$. Is it also neccesery?

The non-degenerate case is also not interesting, i.e. when the $\lambda$'s are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the matrix with columns $a_i$, $\lambda$ is a vectors of $\lambda_i$, $\alpha$, and so on. The condition $$ \mu^T \cdot (b - \sum_j \alpha_j a_j I_{\mu^T \cdot a_j < 0} ) \geq 0$$ is equivalent to the following matrix inequality:

$$ \left(
  \begin{array}{c} \mu \\ z \\
  \end{array}
\right)
^T\cdot \left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
   A & 0 \\
    I & I \\
  \end{array}
\right) \geq 0
$$ implies $$ \left(
  \begin{array}{c} \mu \\ z \\
  \end{array}
\right)
^T\cdot \left(
  \begin{array}{c} b \\ \alpha \\
  \end{array}
\right) \geq 0$$

now use farkas lemma to find $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\lambda_2) \geq 0$
such that $A\lambda_1=b$ and the second matrix row gives $\lambda_1 \leq \alpha$ as needed.